# How to insert a string at the beginning of all items in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to insert a list of strings into a list of a list of numbers. So I have a list of strings as shown and I want to append only the first index of the string list to the first index of all the items in the first list.

input : `['Box_1', 'Box_2, 'Box_3', etc]`
input2: `[[0, 1, 1, 2], [2, 5, 7, 8], [4, 6, 6, 7]]`

required output: `[['Box_1_0', 'Box_1_1', Box_1_1', 'Box_1_2'], ['Box_2_2', 'Box_2_5', 'Box_2_7', 'Box_2_8'], etc]`

This is what I have so far, but its not working

```
for box_list in time_list:
    l = []
    n = 0
    for batch_num in new_list_files[n]:
        n +=1
        for i in batch_list:
            i = batch_num + str(i)
            l.append(l)
    list_final.append(l)
```

Comment: time_list is the list of list of numbers, new_list_files is the list of strings

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: `list_final = [[f"{box}_{i}" for i in time] for time, box in zip(time_list, new_list_files)]`

Comment: Thanks Johnny that worked

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, also make sure that your box list has the proper syntax:

```
box_list = ['Box_1', 'Box_2', 'Box_3']
time_list = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [2, 5, 7, 8], [4, 6, 6, 7]]

new_list = []

for i in box_list:
    for time in time_list:
        new_list.append([f'{i}_{x}' for x in time])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using list comprehension you can have something like this:

```py
box_list = ['Box_1', 'Box_2', 'Box_3']
time_list = [[0, 1, 1, 2], [2, 5, 7, 8], [4, 6, 6, 7]]
new_list = [ f"{val}_{x}" for idx, val in enumerate(box_list) for x in time_list[idx]]
print(new_list)
```